# roslyn project configuration

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis and .MSBuild to load up solution, it's projects and retrieve project OutputFilePath. Trouble is Debug and Release have different ones and I can't figure out a way to switch between solution configurations. Any idea how to set which configuration will be used?

```
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = true;
Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync("someSolution.sln").Result;
foreach (Project project in solution.Projects)
            Console.Out.WriteLine(project.OutputFilePath);
workspace.CloseSolution();
```

Comment: Try passing a dictionary with the entry `{ "Configuration", "Debug" }` (or "Release") to the `MSBuildWorkspace.Create()` method.

Comment: Glad it helped. I had/have no computer to validate it. Turned it into an answer with a little more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some MSBuild properties, like typically the output path, depend on the configuration that the project is built with. You have to specify that configuration when you create the workspace.

For example:

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "Configuration", "Debug" } // Or "Release", or whatever is known to your projects.
   // ... more properties that could influence your property,
   // e.g. "Platform" ("x86", "AnyCPU", etc.)
};

MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(properties);
workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = true;
Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync("someSolution.sln").Result;
foreach (Project project in solution.Projects)
            Console.Out.WriteLine(project.OutputFilePath);
workspace.CloseSolution();
```